# C++ Segmentation fault while printing the elements of the struct in the linked list

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, linked-list

compiler gives me segmentation fault when i have more than 2 structs in the linked list.

i have a struct `Car` that contains info about the car

```c
struct Car {
        string name;
        string color;
        int serialNumber;
        int regestrationNumber;
        int yearMade;
        int yearInspection;
        int price;
};
```

and i have a linked list

```c++
struct Node {
    Car obj;
    struct Node* next;
};
```

that i declare like that:

```cpp
struct Node* head = NULL;
```

i collect info with this code block

```cpp
    cout << "name: " ;
    getline(cin, newCar[size].name);
    cout << "color: ";
    getline(cin, newCar[size].color);
    cout << "serial number: ";
    cin >> newCar[size].serialNumber;
    cout << "regestration number: ";
    cin >> newCar[size].regestrationNumber;
    cout << "year made: ";
    cin >> newCar[size].yearMade;
    cout << "inspection year: ";
    cin >> newCar[size].yearInspection;
    cout << "price: ";
    cin >> newCar[size].price;
    cin.get();
```

i add all this info to struct and push that struct to the linked-list with this function

```cpp
void push(struct Node** head, Car node_obj)
{
    Node* newNode = newNode;
    newNode->obj = node_obj;
    newNode->next = (*head);
    (*head) = newNode;
}
```

and now the interesting part:
i use function `void output(Car strk, int first)` to print the content of struct like this  (`output()` is basically a three `printf()` function)

```cpp
while (headCopy != NULL) {
    output(headCopy->obj, first);

    headCopy = headCopy->next;
    first = 1;
}
```

and now, when linked list has more than 2 elements in it it shows all the elements except for the first one, where it says `segmentation fault`.
i assume that the problem is that by the end `headCopy = headCopy->next;` simply doesn't point to anything or something, but then again, why doesn't it gives me that error when it has 1 or 2 elements.

Comment: `Node* newNode = newNode;` is wrong. Did you mean `Node* newNode = new Node;`?

Comment: Hack trick: `push` can take head by reference to eliminate the dereferences and take advantage of [Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) and be reduced to `void push(struct Node*& head, Car node_obj) { 
    head = new Node {node_obj, head}; }`

Comment: @user4581301 - that is clever -- the shortest *forward-chaining* add around `:)`

Comment: Clever, but not clever enough to avoid the ambiguity of two "and"s in a row. Damn the English language.

Comment: @MikeVine yes you are completely right thank you

Answer (score 1):

as @mike vine said the problem was with line

```cpp
Node* newNode = newNode;
```

where i should've typed

```cpp
Node* newNode = new Node;
```

very stupid mistake.